# timeIntervalSince1970 issue in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Just switched to swift 3.0 after 30 minutes of error fixes I finally got it down to one error

```
let timeStamp = NSNumber(Int(Date().timeIntervalSinceNow))
//error: Argument Labels(_:)'do not match any available overloads
```

Not sure what this means because I never ran into this issue. I have this function wrapped in a `fileprivate function(_propterties [String: AnyObject]){}`

Thanks. Looks like I have a lot to learn with swift 3.0

Comment: Don't use `NSNumber` in Swift.

Comment: `let past: Date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)`, it is working flawlessly, but your post does not really match your post's title.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I guess I just got tired of all the errors and kinda gave up. Got it working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the argument-label `value` in `NSNumber`'s initializer:

```
let timeStamp = NSNumber(value: Date().timeIntervalSinceNow)
```

Have a look at the documentation of `NSNumber`: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumber/1407545-init

---

Additionally, you don't need to convert the [`TimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timeinterval) returned by `timeIntervalSinceNow` to an `Int`. `TimeInterval` is a typealias of `Double` and there is an initializer to create a `NSNumber` from a `Double`.

Comment: Perfect! Hmm...interesting. Why does Int(Date) not work anymore? Just curious.

Comment: @Ketone The error is not that `Int(Date)` is not working. The error is that you are trying to init an `NSNumber` without a label on the initial parameter.

Comment: I see. So I just got away with it in Swift 2. Thanks everyone. That makes more sense now.

Comment: @Ketone having said all of that... still don't use `NSNumber` in Swift (unless you're saving something to CoreData... and then still don't because you should be saving the Date not the TimeInterval).

Comment: @Ketone Swift 3 changed syntax so that the label of first parameter of the `init` method was required. This was not the case in Swift 2.

Comment: I am actually saving the time interval as  a "string" to FIRBase. Only using it so that I can populate data in chronologic order. It is the only method I have been using. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: @Ketone If you want a `String` then make a string. Not an `NSNumber`. `let string = "\(theDate.timeIntervalSince1970)"` This will create a string out of the time interval. No need to cast it to anything.

Comment: "var values: [String: AnyObject] = [...,"timeStamp": timeStamp]" setting  NSNumber as "String" sorry typo above. essentially I am doing the same thing you just posted @Fogmeister. I just have other object to send to FIRBase so I set a value timeStamp for the NSNumber to make the code easier to read.  Have not had an issue with using this method.

Comment: @Ketone yes. But you are using a redundant data type (NSNumber) in a language that does not require it. Just don't use it. If you had not used it you would not have had to ask this question in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I thought I was making it easier. Till I ran into an issue. Thanks Fogmeister.

Comment: @Ketone no worries. Glad you got it working in the end :-)